# Creating a TagsBlock for StreamField

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'm trying to create a struck block, which has a tags field so the user could choose the tags he wants to filter from.
I created the tags field using `wagtail.admin.widgets import AdminTagWidget`.

```
class TagsBlock(FieldBlock):
    field = forms.CharField(
        widget=AdminTagWidget
        )

class RelatedArticlesBlock(StructBlock):
    title = CharBlock(required=False)
    filter_tags = TagsBlock()
    no_of_items = IntegerBlock()
```

It works as expected for selecting tags. But when I save it gives validation errors because the filter_tags field is empty.

What should I do to fix this? (The input is not populating with the selected tags)

[image: Works as expected for selecting tags]

[image: Validation errors because the filter_tags field is empty]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slight refinement, setting the `field` in the `__init__` call appears to work.

Based on the docs relating to [custom block types](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/streamfield.html#custom-block-types).

```py
from django import forms

from wagtail.admin.widgets import AdminTagWidget

# ...

class TagsBlock(FieldBlock):
    """
    Basic Stream Block that will use the Wagtail tags system.
    Stores the tags as simple strings only.
    """

    def __init__(self, required=False, help_text=None, **kwargs):
        # note - required=False is critical if you are adding this block to an existing streamfield (or you can set up your manual migrations to avoid this need)
        self.field = forms.CharField(widget=AdminTagWidget, required=False)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

LB Ben Johnston helped me putting tags into blocks, but I eventually ran into the same error youd did as I couldn't leave the tag field empty. To fix it I modified the above (LB Ben Jonston's answer) so that the the TagsBlock is now:

```
class TagsBlock(blocks.FieldBlock):
    """
    Basic Stream Block that will use the Wagtail tags system.
    Stores the tags as simple strings only.
    """

    def __init__(self, required=False, help_text=None, **kwargs):
        self.field = forms.CharField(widget=AdminTagWidget, required=False)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

The `required=False` is now inside the self.field.

This allowed me to leave the tag field empty if the user wants to.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

LB Ben Johnston's answer helped but required small addition (at least for me). It works perfect when I create new Page but doesn't show saved tags. The reason is that form fields for StreamField are generated with js and on moment when AdminTagWidget is being rendered `field` doesn't have value. Value is added later with js. To avoid this I had to update `tag_widget.html` slightly.

Before:

```
{% include 'django/forms/widgets/text.html' %}
<script>
    initTagField(
        "{{ widget.attrs.id|escapejs }}",
        "{{ widget.autocomplete_url|escapejs }}",
        {{ widget.options_json|safe }}
    );
</script>
```

After:

```
{% include 'django/forms/widgets/text.html' %}
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        initTagField(
            "{{ widget.attrs.id|escapejs }}",
            "{{ widget.autocomplete_url|escapejs }}",
            {{ widget.options_json|safe }}
        );
    });
</script>
```

This could be done with overriding `tag_widget.html` in your app or creating new widget:

```
from wagtail.admin.widgets import AdminTagWidget as BaseAdminTagWidget


class AdminTagWidget(BaseAdminTagWidget):
    template_name = "app/widgets/tag_widget.html"
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I had the exact same issue, and your workaround worked like a charm!