# Putting tags in a StructBlock

Tags: django, django-models, tags, wagtail

I want to be able to add tagging to a custom StructBlock that I've created.

The current model looks like this

```
class MapsIndicatorBlock(blocks.StructBlock):

    text_icon = blocks.CharBlock(
        label='Maps/Indicators Text or Icon',
        required=False
    )

    pop_up_title = blocks.CharBlock(
        label='Pop-Up Title',
        required=False
    )

    pop_up_text = blocks.RichTextBlock(
        label ='Pop-Up Text/Image',
        required=False
    )

    pop_up_colour = blocks.CharBlock(
        choices=constants.BOOTSTRAP4_BUTTON_COLOUR_CHOICES,
        default='btn btn-primary',
        max_length=128,
        required=False
    )

    tags = TaggableManager()

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        template = 'cityregiontable/map_indicator_block.html'
```

The TaggableManager() was designed to be used with models.model not blocks.StructBlock.

I have tried to create a way to create the tags using the following to no avail. I get the error RE: not being able to find the model for MapsIndicatorBlock. This is correct as MapsIndicatorBlock is a block, not a model.

```
class MITag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = models.ForeignKey(
        'MapsIndicatorBlock',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tagged_mi_block'
    )
```

How can I allow a block to be have metadat tags?

Answer (score 7):

Based on the docs for [custom block types](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/streamfield.html#custom-block-types) as a starting point we are able to generate a custom `FieldBlock` that leverages the existing Wagtail [`AdminTagWidget`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/widgets.py#L118).

This widget does almost all of the work for you, it will pull in the available tags for autocomplete plus will save any new tags created on the fly.

It is possible to read out these tags and make them available more conveniently with a model `@property` or similar. Remember Streamfields store data as JSON so you do not get any of the model / database linking out of the box.

### Limitations

The caveat is that the saved tags are stored as the raw strings, this means if you have some more complex use cases of tags you will have to do a bit more work to get this integrated. e.g. a tag page that shows all pages that use that tag or advanced tag editing in Wagtail's `ModelAdmin`.

In these cases, you can either work out a way to 'sync' the Page's tags with the StreamField tag and maybe abstract this work out to a mixin. Alternatively, you can rework your query on your tags page to also include those with the streamfield data you want.

### Example Code

```py
from itertools import chain

from django import forms

from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel
from wagtail.admin.widgets import AdminTagWidget

from wagtail.core.blocks import CharBlock, FieldBlock, StructBlock, RichTextBlock
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.core.models import Page

class TagsBlock(FieldBlock):
    """
    Basic Stream Block that will use the Wagtail tags system.
    Stores the tags as simple strings only.
    """

    def __init__(self, required=False, help_text=None, **kwargs):
        # note - required=False is important if you are adding this tag to an existing streamfield
        self.field = forms.CharField(widget=AdminTagWidget, required=False)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class MapBlock(StructBlock):
    title = CharBlock(label="Title", required=False)
    content = RichTextBlock(label="Content", required=False)
    tags = TagsBlock(label="Tags", required=False)

    class Meta:
        icon = 'site'


class LocationPage(Page):
    """
    Detail for a specific location.
    """

    # ... other fields

    # this is the stream field added
    map_info = StreamField([('Map', MapBlock(required=False))], blank=True)

    @property
    def get_tags(self):
        """
        Helpful property to pull out the tags saved inside the struct value
        Important: makes some hard assumptions about the names & structure
        Does not get the id of the tag, only the strings as a list
        """

        tags_all = [block.value.get('tags', '').split(',') for block in self.test_b]

        tags = list(chain.from_iterable(tags_all))

        return tags

    # Fields to show to the editor in the admin view
    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('title', classname="full"),
        StreamFieldPanel('map_info'),
        # ... others
    ]

    # ... rest of page model
```

Thanks to [this similar question about tags in streamfields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073812/creating-a-tagsblock-for-streamfield/61263982), answering that helped me answer this one.
[Creating a TagsBlock for StreamField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073812/creating-a-tagsblock-for-streamfield/61263982)

Comment: This worked very well. On furthur exploration after posting the question and before I saw your answer, it was looking like I had to create a block, but I wasn't sure how to implement the tagging part as with the AdminTagWidget. This has helped immensely. Thank you!

Comment: I ran into the same problem as I did in your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073812/creating-a-tagsblock-for-streamfield/61263982). It kept saying that the field was required. I fixed that by adding modifying the field inthe TagsBlock to `self.field = forms.CharField(widget=AdminTagWidget, required=False)`. Then I could leave blank fields.

Comment: Awesome, I'll update my answer to cover that, as I was creating a new field on my model it probably did not come up as an issue initially.